# How can I get the length of each element in a LinearRing in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am using JavaScript in Google Earth Engine (very new to both of these) to get the lengths of each side of a building (looking down from map view)

First, I drew a LinearRing around the perimeter of the building, which is stored in the variable `rectangle`. I would like to extract the lengths of each of the lines in `rectangle` and print all of them.

The code I have below so far:

```
var rectangle = /* color: ffffff */ee.Geometry.LinearRing(
    [[coord_1],
     [coord_2],
     [coord_3],
     [coord_4],
     [coord_1]]);

var geometries = rectangle.geometries();
var line1 = geometries.get(0); 
var line2 = geometries.get(1);
print(line2)
```

This gives me an error of:

```
ComputedObject (Error)
List.get: List index must be between -1 and 0.  Found 1.
```

The converted JS code in GEE for `var rectangle` looks like this for reference:

```
var rectangle: LinearRing, 5 vertices
  type: LinearRing
  coordinates: List (5 elements)
    0: [coord_1]
    1: [coord_2]
    2: [coord_3]
    3: [coord_4]
    4: [coord_1]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `.coordinates()` rather than `.geometries()` on your rectangle.

If you had a FeatureCollection, `.geometries()` would get you the geometries of all the features in that collection, while `.coordinates()` returns the coordinates of a single Geometry.